# What's it called when you think you feel better but you are still sick

Tags: single-word-requests

I swear there is a word for thinking something when its really just your mind pretending it.

i.e You are sick and have an Advil and *immediately* feel better. (Even though it might not have kicked in yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the expression ***[placebo effect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/placebo%20effect)***:

> - improvement in the condition of a patient that occurs in response to treatment but cannot be considered due to the specific treatment used.

(M-W)

Comment: Yes this is it, thank you very much.

I realize I described it a little wrong, but this is what I was looking for..